How can I write an EF Core query to achieve a proper entity hierarchy with a self-referencing child?
Problems encountered in code:
After Include-ing Topic[] of Course, then Question[] of Topic, the entity in play now becomes Question.  Desired behavior is to also include SubTopic[] of Topic and Question[] of SubTopic.

less important (this can be solved on the front-end, but keeping object size smaller is better): don't include SubTopic[] at the same level as Topic, which is the current behavior (should Topic.CourseId be nullable?)

public async Task<ActionResult<Course>> GetCourse(int id)
{
    var course = await _context.Courses
        .Include(course => course.Topics)
        .ThenInclude(topic => topic.Questions)
        //.ThenInclude(topic => topic.SubTopics) // lambda param here is a Question, not Topic
        //.ThenInclude(subTopic => subTopic.Questions)
        .ThenInclude(question => question.Answers)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);

    if (course == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return course;
}

Entity schema:
public class Course
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; } = new List<Topic>();

 }

public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; } = null;
    public int? TopicId { get; set; } // self-referential; this makes it a SubTopic
    public Topic ParentTopic { get; set; } = null;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<Topic> SubTopics { get; set; } = new List<Topic>();
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();

}

Database after migration:

Desired object representation in C#:


FYI, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

You just include again and again everytime you want to start from the top. In your case it will be
include topic
theninclude questions
theninclude answers
include topic
theninclude topic


That seems to do the trick!  Any idea how to NOT include SubTopics under Course, but only under other Topics?

If you don't want that link you should make CourseId nullable and make them null for subtopics. If you can't do that then I don't have any good ideas
